# validates_confirmation_of :password doesn't get triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

I have a very basic Admin model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

[According to the manual](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password) `has_secure_password` also adds a `validates_confirmation_of :password`. If I'm correct `validates_confirmation_of` should always error if `:password` and `:password_confirmation` do not match - even if `:password_confirmation` is `nil`.

I'm testing with RSpec and this test fails and tells me that `admin` **is** valid:

```
admin = Admin.new
admin.email = 'test@example.info'
admin.password = 'secret'
admin.should be_invalid
```

This one passes:

```
admin = Admin.new
admin.email = 'test@example.info'
admin.password = 'secret'
admin.password_confirmation = ''
admin.should be_invalid
```

So, what the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the first case, what's the value of `admin.password_confirmation` after setting password to `'secret'`?

Comment: `admin.password_confirmation` is `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code for `has_secure_password`:

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb, line 32
def has_secure_password
  attr_reader :password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of     :password_digest

  include InstanceMethodsOnActivation

  if respond_to?(:attributes_protected_by_default)
    def self.attributes_protected_by_default
      super + ['password_digest']
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see it never ensures that a password confirmation is sent. You could add that yourself however, and as long as you have the form field on your page an empty string will be sent if it is unfilled.

Comment: Right, I should have RTFM: "This check is performed only if `password_confirmation` is not `nil`, and by default only on save." (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_confirmation_of)